# Why expansion is not being done by Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I am trying to run the following code on Wolfram Language:

```
u1=T^2
I1=(2*p2*T^3-2*p1*T^3+3*p1*T^2)/3
I2=(4*p2*T^5-4*p1*T^5+5*p1*T^4)/10
I3=(-2*(p2-p1)*T^3-3*p1*T^2+2*p2+p1)/3
I4=((-4*p2-4*p1)*T^5-5*p1*T^4+4*p2+p1)/10
E1=(2*T*(p1-p2))/(p2-p1)^2
F1=(2*(p2-p1)^3)/(-1-T)^2
h1=(7*T*(p2-p1))/10
h2=p2-p1-T*p2+T*p1
e1=2*I1-(2*I2)/u1+2/3*h1*u1+h2*u1-cl*u1
f1=((2*h1*I2)/(u1^2)+h1^2/3*h1*h2-cl*h1)*E1+2*I1+h1*u1+2*h2*u1-2*cl*u1+((6*(I3-   I4)+h2*(2*u1^2-4*u1+2)+3*cl*(-u1^2+2*u1-1))/3)*F1
g1=f1*(T^3*(p2-p1)^2*(T+1)^2)
Expand[g1]
```

However, the expression I am getting at the end still has denominators of the form $(T^2+2T+1)$ and $(p_2-p_1)$. Why is this? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to see if this does what you want

```
Map[ExpandDenominator, Expand[g1]]
```

Using V 13.3 this gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> But, I actually want to nullify all denominators. in f1 Is there a way
> to do it?

Ok, then how about this

```
g2 = FullSimplify[Expand[g1]]
Expand[g2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: but, I actually want to nullify all denominators. in `f1` Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @vidyarthi see if the update does what you want.

Comment: Thanks! the `g2` is what was required. Great and quick response!